# Error 1400000 Google Play Games

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

More than 12 hours ago I try to publish my game in Google Play Games but I get "An unexpected error occured. Try again later (1400000)". I try to delete and relink app but nothing. How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

This Tweet from April 2014 by Martsin Schultz, who experienced a similar problem, suggests this is the error on Google Play side.
https://twitter.com/martinschultz72/status/461223016991834112 - although, I do admit, this seems to be quite a long time for a Google Play backend issue.

Apart from that, I would try using a different browser, just in case.

Comment: @rickyxd
I think the best thing to do would be contacting Google Play support.

Comment: i send an email to Google Play Support but I resolved the issue creating an Event. Thank you!

Comment: @rickyxd
No problem! Can you please specify how did you solve the issue? It would be quite helpful for others, especially since Error 1400000 is not a popular one on Google.

Comment: I think that is strange but i resolve Error 1400000 adding one Event while before my app has only one LeaderBoard and 5 Achievements, so I suggest to add at least one LeaderBoard and one Event even if you don't use it. I'm not sure that it work for all, but for me is the solution!